# Getting a variable from a function in a child class, and using it in the parent class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent class

```
class ParentFoo extends compenent {
       render () {
            This is where I need the variable from child
            return (
               html
            )
          }
    }
```

I then have another, child class

```
class ChildFoo extends compenent {
      function(){
                var foo = some data
          }
       render () {
    }
```

How can I use that variable, foo, thats inside a function, inside of the child class, in my parent class?

Comment: why don't you use global variable ?

Comment: This (along with @MEnf's answer) will probably work better if you spell `Component` correctly ;-)

Comment: That's what I get for just copying and editing code...  Thanks for pointing that out! haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the variable up to the parent class and pass it down to the child class via props.

```
class ParentFoo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    foo: null
  }

  changeFoo = (value) => {
    this.setState({ foo: value })
  }

  render () {
    return(
      <ChildFoo changeFoo={this.changeFoo} />
      <p>{this.state.foo}</p>
    )
  }
}

const ChildFoo = (props) => {
  const someData = 'whatever info'
  return(
    <button onClick={() => this.props.changeFoo(someData)} />
  )
}
```

Comment: made an edit, because I looked at my code wrong, not sure if it makes a huge difference, but the function is called before the render.

Comment: also, i need the variable outside of the return in the parent

Comment: State can be called outside of the return statement.   By moving your function outside of render, you are no longer rendering anything on to the page.  You will not have your html rendered on to it.